# How do I make the file browser open in a specific folder using HTML or Perl?

Tags: html, perl, file-upload

I'm using template toolkit and have the following code to allow the user to upload a .csv file, is it possible to force the file browser to open in a specific folder in the C drive instead of desktop?

```
<form action="/selectExisting" method="post" accept=".csv" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <h2>Existing Competition</h2>
                <p>Please browse and select the pre-existing competition file</p>


                <input type="file" name="file">

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large">
       Upload
     </button>
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. And what if your user is on a Mac or a Unix system? no C: drives there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do it via the HTML form element, and PHP is server-side, so you definitely can't do it that way. I bet there's a way to do it with Java, though. But you should really think out what you mean to do. Not everyone's desktop is going to be arranged the same way.